# SQL Server 2014 only using 10 percent of its available memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory

Hoping someone can weigh in here. I have a 2014 developer edition box that doesn't seem to be performing well. I currently have 128 GBs of RAM allocated to the box and 120 GBs maximum allocated inside of SQL itself.

When I look at the server itself, Windows recognizes it and so does SQL, but it never seems to jump up above 10 percent. All of the other SQL boxes I've built have memory at least sitting at 90 percent or so.

It's running a QA environment that sees maybe 10 users on it at one given time, but I would expect our memory to be using a lot more than it is currently. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: typically read activity against the data base files drives most of the growth of sql server [total server memory]. got any sizable databases attached?  a checkdb with physical_only against a sizable database should motivate sql server to grow [total server memory kb]. can that be tried, monitoring the [\SQLServer:Memory Manager\Total Server Memory (KB)] perfmon counter?

Comment: Use performance counters instead of task manager. `SELECT counter_name, cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name IN('Total Server Memory (KB)', 'Target Server Memory (KB)');`

Comment: Above graph may be for a very small interval of time, say when no load/queries are being run in QA. Try to capture these metrics over a period of time and compare memory usage VS Batch req/sec. Or probably you dont have that much huge amount of data in database to load pages in RAM

Answer (score -1):

if you what that sql server reservs an amount of ram you have to configure minimum server memory.
In your case the min server memory is zero; then sql server takes only the ram it nees to answer the users' queries.

Change it in this way:

```
EXEC sp_configure N'min server memory (MB)', MBs_you_like
RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: [min server memory] is a lower bound for [total server memory] once it has been achieved. But [min server memory] doesn’t play it’s role until there’s been enough activity to cause [total server memory] to grow that far.